# Attach a local cssTheme stylesheet to a site I don't have access to

Tags: css

I'm looking for a solution to achieve this. A website that I print out a lot from, has a horrible printing format. I wonder is it possible to attach my own css somehow, so I can format how it prints.

Comment: Sure it is. Just inject your style sheet into the sites header. Easiest is to do this manually by copying the reference into the source shown in your browsers development console.

Comment: What browser do you use?